# Notation problem in polynomial rings. What is $\mathfrak{p}R[x]$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have seen a lot the notation "$\mathfrak{p}R[x]$", where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal and $R[x]$ is a polynomial ring with coefficients in $R$.

My first question is: What is $\mathfrak{p}R[x]$ exactly? I think that it is not the same as $\mathfrak{p}[x]$, whose elements are polynomials with coefficients in $\mathfrak{p}$.

Just to give some context, I am trying to prove that $1 + \dim(R) ≤ \dim(R[X]) ≤ 1 + 2 \dim(R)$. And the first thing that appears in every single proof I've seen is the prime ideals chain $$\mathfrak{p}_0R[x]\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}_1R[x]\subsetneq\dots\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}_nR[x]\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}_nR[x]+(x).$$
Somehow, there is a relationship between the ideals of $R$ and the ideals of $R[x]$, but I am not able to spot it.

Comment: It denotes the extension of the prime ideal $\mathfrak p \in \operatorname{Spec}R$ to the polynomial ring $R[X]$, just as it can be extended to any $R$-algebra B (=(extension denoted $\mathfrak p B$). You can check, in the case of the polynomial ring, that it consists of  the polynomials which have all their coefficients in $\mathfrak p$.

Comment: But how is the extension defined? I mean, we have a particular ring homomorphism $\phi$ from R to R[x]?

Comment: It's just the canonical injection. A constant is a polynomial of degree $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a notation for the ideal generated by the set $\mathfrak{p}$. Let me specify that:

It gets used when you have a ring extension $R \rightarrow S$ and want to describe the ideal generated by the image of the a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset R$.

In this case, the extension is the inclusion $R \subset R[x]$.

Comment: So, in this case, the ring extension is $\phi:R \longrightarrow R[x]$, where $\phi(r)=r$, a constant polynomial?

Comment: Yes, the inclusion from $R$ to $R[x]$.

Comment: But then, $\mathfrak{p}R[x]$ is the same than $\mathfrak{p}[x]$?